# SQL Stored Procedure returning 0 ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @RC INT = 0;
    BEGIN
        update CustomerRecord set IsDeleted=0 where CustomerID=@CustomerID;
    END
    SET @RC = @@ROWCOUNT
    PRINT @RC

    return @RC;
END
```

I am expecting the result to be 1 but it's returning 0.
I queried the table and it did change the data

Comment: You may need to move it inside the `begin/end`. What is the purpose of that anyway?

Comment: How are you retrieving that value outside the procedure?

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT will give you the count from previous operation. In this case BEGIN END Block. If you will move it right after UPDATE statement, it should read the number of records touched by the previous command, in this case the UPDATE statement

Comment: Doesn't look like the `BEGIN`/`END` make any difference here https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6qC7.png

Comment: I'm wondering if something got stripped though.

Comment: @shawnt00 it is being returned from the SP. It should be non-zero to indicate data was modified

Comment: A return value is entirely different from `@@rowcount`. That's why I ask.

Comment: it used to return @@rowcount, i modified the code to see if it had been returning any value. Unfortunately that value is 0, is there another way to determine if the update statement modified any records?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you modified exactly. The main question is to first determine that the return value/output parameter is being checked correctly. It sounds like that may be the case but that's what we need to confirm.

Comment: let me post the entire SP. Maybe I made an error and don't see it. I was posting the minimal viable example

Comment: Showing the procedure call would be a good start.

Comment: Unless I missed it in the comments are you saying it prints 1 but returns 0, or it prints 0 also?

Comment: _is there another way to determine_ Yes. Either you check @@ROWCOUNT immediately after the UPDATE statement or use an OUTPUT clause. But do you really need to check at all? Something is TERRIBLY wrong if the caller of a procedure is supplying a parameter value that does not exist in your table. Don't encourage lazy coding IMO. An alternative would be to throw an error if there is no matching row (which you should do as the first action in your logic).

Answer (score 1):

Try following SP:

```
CREATE Procedure dbo.SpTest
(
@CustomerID int
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RC INT = 0;
    BEGIN
         UPDATE CustomerRecord set IsDeleted=0 where CustomerID=@CustomerID;
    END
SET @RC = @@ROWCOUNT
    PRINT @RC
    return @RC;
END
```

AND Run as Follow:

```
exec dbo.SpTest
```

If a record or records are updated, the result will be printed in the output.

[image: The output of the code will look like this.]